# What does SELECT Function is SQL actually produce? Does it produce a new table by default?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am struggling to understand what the output of SELECT is meant to be in SQL (I am using MS ACCESS), and what sort of criteria this output needs to specify, if any. As a result, I don't understand why some queries work and others don't. So I know it retrieves data from a table, does calculations with it and displays it. But I don't understand the "inner" working of SELECT function. For instance, what is the name of data structure  / entity it displays? Is it a  "new" table?

And for example, suppose I have a table called "table_name", with 5 columns. One of the columns called "column_3", and there are 20 records.

```
SELECT  column_3, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM table_name;
```

Why does this query fail to run? By logic, I would expect it to display two columns: first column will be "column_3", containing 20 rows with relevant data, and second column will be "Count", containing just one non-empty row (displaying 20), and other 19 rows will be empty (or NULL maybe)?

Is it because SELECT is meant to produce equal number of rows for each column?

Comment: I think I can remember a query like that working on older versions of some databases (more specifically, I am thinking about Oracle back when it was in a single-digit version numbers). It wouldn't work the way you described it, though: a table simply repeated the count in each row of the return. This may or may not still work like that today (or it could also be a false memory of mine). Although there are situations when doing something like this would make your life easier, most DB engines consider this an error.

Comment: Why would this kind of a query be considered an error by most DB engines though? Simply because of how it was made to be?

Comment: I guess you can say so, yes. Essentially, DB engines require that aggregating and non-aggregating parts of a query to be in separate queries, except the columns on which you group. To the DB engine, these two parts look unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions involve a basic understanding of SQL. SELECT statements do not create tables, but instead return virtual result sets. Nothing is persisted unless you change it to an INSERT.

In your example question, you will need to "tell" the SQL engine what you want a count "of". Because you added column_3, you need to write:

```
SELECT column_3, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY column_3
```

If you wanted a count of all the rows, simply:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I know that I need to include GROUP BY in my example question. However I don't understand why my query, as I wrote, gives an error? Why doesn't it return what I expected it to return (as written in my post) ? Another thing. What is a virtual return set, and what do you mean by "persisted"? Why can I save my query, and run new SELECT queries on the existing one?  @DanielG

Comment: As to why your syntax does not work, this is just how ANSI compliant SQL works and beyond the scope of my simple response. :-) When I use the phrases "vitrual" return set, I mean that the results you see or get back in your application are only a snapshot of the data at the moment you ran the query. Once SQL gives you back the results of a SELECT statement, it's your job to do something with it. MS Access has the concept of saved queries. In SQL Server, a very similar thing is called a VIEW. In Access you can run nested queries, and in SQL Server, you can have nested views.

Comment: PS. When you save a Query in the Access DB container, Access does not store a copy of the data. It simply stores the SQL Statement itself (i.e. SELECT coulmn_3 FROM my table) along with a friendly name you see in the Access database container. When you click the Query in the DB container (or run DoCmd.OpenQuery "myQuery", etc.), Access runs the SQL statement and returns the data (or performs an UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, etc.) as it exists at that time. This may be something causing you some confusion.